# How to combat the "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys' " error in selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I wanted to input something in a textbox. So i opened up the webpage, clicked on the area of the textbox, then clicked on the texbox. However I recieve this error

```
tab = tab.send_keys("title")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

Here is the code i tried.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv
import time

response = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users\jag\PycharmProjects\seleniumTest\drivers\chromedriver.exe')
response.implicitly_wait(20)
response.get("https://reqbin.com/")

tab = response.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='reqForm']/ul/li[3]/a").click()

tab = tab.send_keys("title")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got error because `.click()` method return nothing - `None`.
First you need click on `Content` button.
Entering a text to the **textarea** in the website is a little bit tricky. To activate **textarea** you should click on specific div. Find below example how you can enter text:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users\jag\PycharmProjects\seleniumTest\drivers\chromedriver.exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)


driver.get("https://reqbin.com/")

# Content button
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[href='#pills-req-content']").click()
# wait to be clickable and click to the DIV to activate textarea
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#pills-req-content .CodeMirror"))).click()
# enter text
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#pills-req-content .CodeMirror textarea").send_keys("title")
```

To enter multiline text use `\n`, like: *this text is multiline`\n`this is next line*

Answer (score 2):

`.click()` returns None. You probably want to do them separately:

```
tab = response.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='reqForm']/ul/li[3]/a")
tab.click()
tab.send_keys("title")
```

Comment: i don't get an error now. But it doesnt add the "title" text either.